# Apply data from subscribe to the List

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Goal:
Retrieve the output data

```
 { age: 4, name: 'Foo' }
 { age: 7, name: 'Bar' }
```

and then apply the output data in the variable list named "PersonList: Person[] = [];"

Problem:
I tried different solution about how to apply the output data to the variable PersonList but I failed.

Today I don't know how to do it.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ztwnpx?file=index.ts

Thank you!

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { distinct } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Person {
   age: number,
   name: string
}

of<Person>(
    { age: 4, name: 'Foo'},
    { age: 7, name: 'Bar'},
    { age: 5, name: 'Foo'},
  ).pipe(
    distinct((p: Person) => p.name),
  )
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// displays:
// { age: 4, name: 'Foo' }
// { age: 7, name: 'Bar' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're missing here, but you just need to put the data into an array...

```
let personList = []; // initialize array

of<Person>(
    { age: 4, name: 'Foo'},
    { age: 7, name: 'Bar'},
    { age: 5, name: 'Foo'},
  ).pipe(
    distinct((p: Person) => p.name),
  )
  .subscribe(x => personList.push(x)); // add it to the array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [toArray](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray) operator:

```
import { distinct, toArray } from "rxjs/operators";

let persons: Person[];

of<Person>(
  { age: 4, name: "Foo" },
  { age: 7, name: "Bar" },
  { age: 5, name: "Foo" }
)
  .pipe(
    distinct((p: Person) => p.name),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    persons = x;
  });

console.log(persons);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ztwnpx-qsbzh3?file=index.ts)**

or you can simply use Observable:

```
const persons$: Observable<Person[]> = of<Person>(
  { age: 4, name: "Foo" },
  { age: 7, name: "Bar" },
  { age: 5, name: "Foo" }
)
  .pipe(
    distinct((p: Person) => p.name),
    toArray()
  );
```